# Unable to consistently detect lock/unlock in iOS Swift application

Tags: ios, swift, security

I need to detect lock & unlock events in my Swift application.

I have tried using App Delegate functions like [`applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623019-applicationprotecteddatawillbeco) (to detect lock event) and [`applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623044-applicationprotecteddatadidbecom) (to detect unlock event) but they have proven to be inconsistent.
The function `applicationProtectedDataWillBecomeUnavailable` is not called immediately when the phone is locked and some of the lock events are being missed altogether.
Can you suggest an approach that can guarantee the detection of lock & unlock everytime?

(This issue is not OS specific, and all the devices I have tested on have a passcode to unlock it.)